# Include layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, include, android-xml

I have 3 windows in my android app. So, I think there will be 3 activities. There is also a Navigation Drawer. Navigation Drawer must be available on every Activity. I used pattern Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio. There are 3 xml-layouts:

1). activity_main.xml – has a NavigationView , includes app_bar_main.xml

2). app_bar_main.xml –includes content_main.xml

3). content_main.xml – here will be some content (text, pics, etc.)

Every Activity has, of course, different content. So every Activity has its own content_main.xml. I need to change programmatically this layout that is included in app_bar_main.xml (not in activity_main.xml). I tried this:

`CoordinatorLayout mainLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mainLayout.addView(1, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, this, false));`

But the last row is underlined and says that ‘Cannot resolve method inflate()’.

I also tried this:

`CoordinatorLayout mainLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
 View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
 mainLayout.addView(child);`

But this shows the text of content_main.xml on Toolbar title. So one text overlays another.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [Fragments](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20fragments). It will help you to opn various layouts in the same activity whenever they are called upon. Furthermore, you can reuse your Navigation drawer too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup your child view LayoutParams like:

```
CoordinatorLayout mainLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WEIGHT, HEIGHT);
        params.setMargins(MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
        child.setLayoutParams(params);
        mainLayout.addView(child);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it seems too risky, since the size of screens varies. Maybe it's better to use Fragments instead of 'include' as @nothingwhatsoever wrote?